# Drupal: the shortest code to get all results from db_result in an array

Tags: arrays, drupal

I have a short code to get the results of a db_query into an array:

```
$r = db_query('SELECT vid FROM {node_revisions} WHERE nid = %d', $node->nid);
while ($vids[] = db_result($r));
```

The only problem is, that I get an empty array value:

```
Array(
   [] => 105
   [] => 409
   [] =>
)
```

How can I prevent the empty array value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the shortest code to get all results from db_query in an array:

```
for ($vid; $vid = db_result($r); $vids[] = $vid);
```

The resulted array looks now like this:

```
Array(
   [0] => 105
   [1] => 409
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like.

```
$next_result = db_result($r);
while ($next_result)
{
   $vids[] = $next_result;
   $next_result = db_result($r);
}
```

Edit:
Single line using short-circuit syntax.

```
while ($next = db_result($r) && $vids[] = $next);
```

Comment: Ok, but I would it have as short as possible.

Comment: The short-circuit syntax didn't work for me. But thank you for your idea.